# Get params not being passed

Tags: php, slim

I have an API based application written in slim. I have been testing on my local computer and things have been working OK.

I pushed to the server and I noticed that i cant retrieve the parameters passed via a get request

While debugging, i observed the following

1. Post requests are working fine
2. An attempt to use `$_GET['param']` fails as i get an undefined index error.

To get a parameter value in slim, i write

```
$app->request()->get('param');

URL request :    {api}/hospital/get_locations?hospital_id=1
var_dump($_GET): array(1) { ["/hospital/get_locations"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Any pointers as to why this might be happening?

Content of .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]  
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d  
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]  
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: htaccess or other ini settings not allowing GET??

Comment: @User016 What part of the code will you expect me to post? everywhere i used GET? If there is a part of the question you believe posting some code will help clarify, please let me know. Thanx

Comment: @charlietfl will look into that to see the possibilities. Thank you

Comment: Try to change single quotes to double quotes. `$app->request()->get("param")`

Comment: add `var_dump($_GET)` to your script and then make a request on your script/site url like `http://yoursite.com/?param=xyz` what do you get?

Comment: @LatheesanKanes var_dump($_GET) prints array(1) { ["/hospital/get_locations"]=> string(0) "" }. I am assuming slim is making some changes to the $_GET parameters. The request url is {api}/hospital/get_locations?hospital_id=1

Comment: Can you post the contents of your `.htaccess` in use

Comment: @LatheesanKanes i have added it to the question

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**

There might be a way of getting `get` request params using the `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`. I did a quick test on my localhost and came up with the following. Try it out, might work for you.

**php**

```
<?php

// Function
function getParams() {
    $params = array();
    $urlParts = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
    if (isset($urlParts['query'])) {
        $query = $urlParts['query'];
        if (-1 !== strpos($query, '&')) {
            $query = explode('&', $query);
        } else {
            $query = array($query);
        }
        foreach ($query as $queryStr) {
            list($key, $val) = explode('=', $queryStr);
            $params[$key] = $val;
        }
    }
    return $params;
}

// Usage
$params = getParams();

// Debug
echo "<pre>";
print_r($params);
echo "</pre>";

?>
```

**output**

```
Array
(
    [hospital_id] => 1
)
```

**.htaccess** (similar to yours)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

    RewriteRule .* index.php [L]

</IfModule>
```